# Python: Checking for the values of three variables at the same time

Tags: python, string, string-conversion

I have three randomly generated floats, a, b and c:

```
a = np.random.uniform(-99.999, 99.999)
b = np.random.uniform(-99.999, 99.999)
c = np.random.uniform(-99.999, 99.999)
```

And I would like to return them in the following format:

```
         1         2         3         4         5         
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567
#########################################################RULER

SOMETHING ELSE  ~   ~   ~   ~    -XX.XXX -XX.XXX -XX.XXX
```

Now I need a way to check:

- First, if the each variable is positive or negative, because the sign has be always at position 34(a), 42(b) and 50(c), if the corresponding value is negative.
- Second, if the number before the comma/dot has two digits or one digit. In the second case, we would need another space.

So each value of variable a, b and c can be (positive or negative) and (above 10 or below 10) and the goal is to write the number always to the exact same location (adjusted by spaces).

So far to the problem.

My python knowledge is still pretty basic. What I would do, would probably involve more than 50 lines of code, including...

```
if x >= 0 and x // 10 != 0: #check if x is larger than 0 and has two digits
   if y >= 0 and y // 10 != 0: #check if y is larger than 0 and has two digits 
      ...
```

but there must be a more elegant solution, maybe even a one liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting this question as "I want to convert each of my floats into a string, adding however many spaces is necessary to make them exactly seven spaces long".

You don't actually need *any* conditionals for this. The str.format method can apply the padding to your value without you having to count decimal places or anything.

```
>>> a = 1.0
>>> b = -23.42
>>> c = 5.678
>>> result = "{: 7} {: 7} {: 7}".format(a,b,c)
>>> print(result)
    1.0  -23.42   5.678
```

If you're thinking "ok, but I also want the number to display exactly three digits after the decimal point, even if they're zeroes," then you can do:

```
>>> "{:7.3f} {:7.3f} {:7.3f}".format(a,b,c)
'  1.000 -23.420   5.678'
```

If you're thinking "ok, but I also want the padding to appear *after* the sign but *before* the digits," then you can do:

```
>>> a = -1.0
>>> "{:=7.03f} {:=7.03f} {:=7.03f}".format(a,b,c)
'- 1.000 -23.420   5.678'
```

If you're thinking "ok, but can the padding be zeroes instead of spaces? So then every number has exactly two digits before the decimal point", then you can do:

```
>>> "{:0= 7.03f} {:0= 7.03f} {:0= 7.03f}".format(a,b,c)
'-01.000 -23.420  05.678'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to combine your three if statements. You can extend this idea for your task

```
x, y, z = 12, 24, 16

if all(item > 0 and item // 10 != 0 for item in [x,y,z]):
    print ("Condition matched")
else:
    print ("Condition not matched")

# x, y, z = 12, 24, 16
# Condition matched

# x, y, z = 12, 24, 6
# Condition not matched
```

Comment: Ok, but now, you would have to do another statement like this for all the negative numbers x,y,z can have and then also all combinations.

Comment: This is a satisfactory solution if the OP only needs a yes-or-no answer to "do all three of my values meet the criteria I have set?". But I get the impression that they're actually looking for greater detail, i.e. "which of my values meet the criteria, and specifically which parts of the criteria do they meet, and which do they fail?"

Comment: @Kevin: Ok, but then is such involve case, a one liner would be over ambitious and if possible, too confusing IMO. I will leave my answer though in case the OP can built up something along these lines. I can delete it  if needed though